# Create a proxy with java web application to connect kibana with elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, http-proxy

Hi I am wondering if there is any chance that i can connect kibana with elastic search with a java web app proxy? presently in kibana config.js the code is like below to connect elasticsearch

```
elasticsearch: "http://elasticsearch_host:9200"
```

But i want something like below,

```
elasticsearch: "http://javaapp_host:8080/web-app/KibanaProxy(servlet/jsp)
```

could someone tell me that how can i achieve this??

Comment: You need to write a proxy and make the setting change you have put in the question

Comment: yeah @VineethMohan i just wanted to know is that even possible?

Comment: Why not , the webapp need to accept the query , make the modifications and shoot it to ES and return the response.

Answer (score 0):

The webapp need to accept the query , make the modifications and shoot it to ES and return the response.
Here is a sample Kibana proxy made in nodeJS

Kibana Proxy - https://github.com/fangli/kibana-authentication-proxy

Comment: If there are anything which is related to java much appreciated

Comment: Not that  i know. But its the same process. Intercept the query and forward it.